# How to display different df in plotly with an menue

Tags: python, pandas, filter, plotly, visible

I'd like to display an plotly plot with the ability to change / filter the df with an dropdownmenue.

| TimeStamp | L001_1 | L001_2 | L001_3 | L002_1 | L002_2 | L003_1 | L003_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.1.2023 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 2 |
| 2.1.2023 | 2 | 4 | 5 | 4 | 6 | 4 | 3 |

```
df_L001 = df.filter(regex='L001|TimeStamp')
df_L001 = df_L001.set_index('TimeStamp')

df_L002 = df.filter(regex='L002|TimeStamp')
df_L002 = df_L002.set_index('TimeStamp')

df_L003 = df.filter(regex='L003|TimeStamp')
df_L003 = df_L003.set_index('TimeStamp')


x = df['TimeStamp'].unique()



fig = go.Figure()




for col in df_L001.columns[1:]:
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(y=df_L001[col], x=df_L001.index, name=col))
for col in df_L002.columns[1:]:
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(y=df_L002[col], x=df_L002.index, name=col))
for col in df_L003.columns[1:]:
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(y=df_L003[col], x=df_L003.index, name=col))


fig.update_layout(title_text='Load',
                 xaxis_title='Date', yaxis_title='Load')


fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        dict(active=0,
            buttons=list([
            dict(label="None",
                 method="update",
                 args=[{"visible":[True,True,True]},
                       {"title":"ALL"}]),
            dict(label="L001",
                 method="update",
                 args=[{"visible":[True, False, False]},
                       {"title":"L001"}]),
            dict(label="L002",
                 method="update",
                 args=[{"visible":[False,True,False]},
                       {"title":"L002"}]),
            dict(label="L003",
                 method="update",
                 args=[{"visible":[False,False,True]},
                       {"title":"L003"}]),
        ]),
        )
    ]
)

fig.show()
```

I get it, that the "visible":[False,False,True] is wrong, but I don't find a solution.

Thanks

Comment: Since the graph I am creating is a 4 line graph, I would need 4 True/False elements for the list to be controlled from the dropdown.

Comment: But the graph has 7 lines ( and much more in real ). So the True/False element is not practicalbe in this way.

Comment: You can see the data of the graph structure in `fig.data`. According to it, it consists of four scatter plots.